# java implement google checkout serial-number notification

Tags: java, google-checkout

I want to implement serial-number notification for google checkout as I do not have a domain name but a static ip. I have gone through [Implementing the Notification XML API](http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_XML_API_Notification_API.html) of google checkout and what I have understood is that there are two ways to get notifications:

1.) Have a SSL certificate on server and provide a URL in google checkout account and google will send either XML or HTML notifications on that URL.

2.) Google sends serial-number notification to our application and then that serial-number is used to get other notifications from google.

Now my question is that in case 2 above we do not need a SSL certificate to get serial-number notification. But when application uses serial-number to get other notifications using Notification History API then at that time also server do not need to have SSL certificate or will it be necessary to have a SSL certificateget to get other notifications.

Also can you please provide me some links or sample codes to implement serial number notification in java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct on (1) and (2) - these are you 2 options.

You do not need SSL certificate for your handler if you implement Serial Number Notification.

Another difference between (1) and (2) is that Google will not send Basic Authentication headers to your handler in Serial Number Notification (they do for XML and name/value).

The latter part of your question, JAVA code sample isn't something I can help you with (am .Net). Perhaps this [tutorial](http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_Custom_Processing_How_To.html) can help - it also mentions their [Java SDK](http://code.google.com/p/google-checkout-java-sdk/w/list).